# How to add lat/lon grid lines to JMapViewer

Tags: java, jmapviewer

When using JMapViewer, is there any way to automatically display lat/lon grid lines?  The `JMapViewer.setTileGridVisible` method is unfortunately not the same thing.  I know it's possible to do it manually, but then I have to figure out when to display what resolutions, etc.  Sounds like a pain.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can override `mouseMoved()` in `DefaultMapController` using the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16952806/230513). In the handler, you can update a label or set a tooltip, for example:

```
new DefaultMapController(map) {

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        map.setToolTipText(map.getPosition(e.getPoint()).toString());
    }
};
```

Comment: I apparently need a more obvious indicator.  For now, I've subclassed `JMapViewer`, overridden the `paint`, and drew some strings on the edges.  I might paint the grid lines when I have more time to figure it out.